# Oracle Join two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to execute the following join. 
What i would like to have is a extra column where for the time is displayed next to f_start and also for f_stop
The link between the two tables is the K_id= f_start, f_stop.
Im also joining the d_mac table on this

Table D_time

```
K_id   A_time
1      00:00:00
2      00:01:00
3      00:02:00
4      00:03:00
```

**table f_st**

```
f_start   f_stop f_rs
1           3     MC
2           4     MC
```

**table D_mac**

```
d_id  d_com
1     MC
2     D
```

What would the best way to create the desired table(see below)

**table f_st**

```
f_start f_start_time  f_stop f_stop_time  f_rs
1          00:00:00     3      00:02:00    MC
2          00:01:00     4      00:03:00    MC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the time table twice and give it an alias name.

```
select fst.f_start f_start, f_startTime.A_time f_start_time, 
       fst.f_stop f_stop, f_stopTime.A_time f_stop_time, 
       fst.f_rs f_rs
from f_st fst 
JOIN D_time f_startTime ON (f_startTime.K_ID = fst.f_start)
JOIN D_time f_stopTime ON (f_stopTime.K_ID = fst.f_stop)
;
```